# ROT-128 oscillating quine (Mutual Quine)

Tags: code-golf, quine

ROT-128 is a variant of ROT-13, where instead of cycling through the 26 letters, you cycle through the 256 possible bytes.  Your task is to create a program that outputs the ROT-128 of its own source. The outputted program *must* also be a valid program and output the original program.

### Scoring

This is code golf, so least number of bytes wins! Ties are broken by number of votes.

Comment: In the interest of searchability, I think these are usually called "mutual quines" (at least that term has been used for several challenges on the site, iirc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## GolfScript, <s>64</s> 48 bytes

```
{ºî»`'.~'+.{128^}%\](}.~û:n;à§®þ§«®û±²¸Þý¥ÜÝ¨ý®þ
```

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for golfing off 16 bytes!*

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=e8K6w67Cu2AnLn4nKy57MTI4Xn0lXF0ofS5-w7s6bjvDoMKnwq7DvsKnwqvCrsO7wrHCssK4w57DvcKlw5zDncKow73CrsO-&input=)

#### Output

```
û:n;à§®þ§«®û±²¸Þý¥ÜÝ¨ý®þ{ºî»`'.~'+.{128^}%\](}.~
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=w7s6bjvDoMKnwq7DvsKnwqvCrsO7wrHCssK4w57DvcKlw5zDncKow73CrsO-e8K6w67Cu2AnLn4nKy57MTI4Xn0lXF0ofS5-&input=)

#### Verification

```
$ LANG=en_US

$ cat quine.gs
{ºî»`'.~'+.{128^}%\](}.~û:n;à§®þ§«®û±²¸Þý¥ÜÝ¨ý®þ
$ golfscript quine.gs
û:n;à§®þ§«®û±²¸Þý¥ÜÝ¨ý®þ{ºî»`'.~'+.{128^}%\](}.~
$ golfscript quine.gs | golfscript
{ºî»`'.~'+.{128^}%\](}.~û:n;à§®þ§«®û±²¸Þý¥ÜÝ¨ý®þ
$ diff -s quine.gs <(golfscript quine.gs | golfscript)
Files quine.gs and /dev/fd/63 are identical
```

Answer (score 4):

## Self-Modifying Brainf*ck, 74 bytes

```
<[<]>[<++++[>++++<-]>[<++++++++>-].>]
```

(The second half of the program is the same as above, except in ROT-128)

Just thought I would post this as a) a kickstart for ideas, and b) showing that it is possible to do without an insanely large program.